# Python: using shiftgrid to change longitude

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, latitude-longitude, matplotlib-basemap

I am using python 3.6 to map climate model data that has the original longitude of `(0,360)`. I using a `basemap` function called `shiftgrid` in order to shift all of the longitude values in my data set to `(-180,180)`. However I am still getting an empty map. Any suggestions would be helpful. Thanks!

Here is my code so far:

```
#Longitude values:
a=0
b=360

prcp = np.load('data.npy')

data=np.average(prcp,axis=0)

plt.figure()
# create Basemap
x1 = np.linspace(a,b, data.shape[1])
y1 = np.linspace(-90, 90, data.shape[0])
xx1, yy1 = np.meshgrid(x1, y1)

data, x1 = shiftgrid(180., data, x1,start= False)
```

Comment: I guess that you have to call `shiftgrid` before creating of meshgrid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've run into these kind of problems myself. My solution was to transform the co-ordinates of the input file using `cdo` (there is a python front end available for `cdo`). The shift can be done with:

```
cdo sellonlatbox,-180,180,-90,90 input.nc output.nc
```

or, if you have the python front end available, you can get the data directly as `netCDF4.Dataset` with

```
from cdo import Cdo
cdo = Cdo()

data = cdo.sellonlatbox(
    '-180,180,-90,90',
    input = 'input.nc',
)
```

Hope this helps.